# init is not called when injecting viewModel using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I want to make API request when ViewModel is initialized. That`s why I make API request inside `init` method; expecting `init` be triggered when I inject viewModel in Activity. What am I doing wrong?

> MainViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val mainRepository: MainRepo) : ViewModel() {
companion object {
    var TAG = "MainViewModel**"
}

init {
    Log.d(TAG, "NOT TRIGGERED: ")

    viewModelScope.launch {
        val album1: List<AlbumItem> = mainRepository.getAlbums()
    }
}}
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mainViewModel : MainViewModel by viewModels() // injecting viewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: `init` will be called when the primary constructor is called, is it called here?

Comment: @Jagar, I can succesfuly crete object to `MainRepo` class. It is created in primary constructor. I think, everything is okay in primary constructor. But there is one case that when I call a function from viewModel inside activity first init triggers, and then that function is called. As I stated in question, I want `init` be triggered when I inject viewModel inside Activity

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are misunderstanding a delegate for injection.

```
private val mainViewModel : MainViewModel by viewModels() // injecting viewModel (Wrong)
```

This is not dagger/hilt injection. This is a call to lazy delegate provided by AndroidKTX. So the behavior you are getting is expected, your ViewModel will be created (not injected) when you first access the property `mainViewModel`. So the timing of your init {} block is expected.

From Dagger/Hilt's documentation (https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html)

> Warning: Even though the view model has an @Inject constructor, it is an error to request it from Dagger directly (for example, via field injection) since that would result in multiple instances. View Models must be retrieved through the ViewModelProvider API. This is checked at compile time by Hilt.

What you can do is access `mainViewModel` in your `onCreate` method and that will trigger the `init` block early as possible.
Or remove the delegate and initialize `mainViewModel` in `onCreate` manually.

```
mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```