# HiltViewModel: NoSuchMethodException on the class annotated by @HiltViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I’m a beginner in making Android applications. I tried to run a simple application for viewing a list of movies. When I ran it, I got this error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.nameful.ui.main.MovieListViewModel.<init> []
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
    ... 94 more
```

This is MovieListViewModel.kt, the class in question:

```
package com.example.nameful.ui.main


import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.paging.PagingData
import androidx.paging.cachedIn
import com.example.nameful.data.package000.GetMovieListUseCase
import com.example.nameful.data.repository.MoviesRepository
import com.example.nameful.data.repository.MoviesRepositoryImpl
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Movie
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.emptyFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MovieListViewModel @Inject constructor(
   private val getMovieListUseCase: GetMovieListUseCase
) : ViewModel() {



   var movieList: Flow<PagingData<Movie>>
   var favoriteMovieList: Flow<List<Movie>>

   init {
       movieList = loadMovies()
       favoriteMovieList = loadFavoriteMovies()
   }


   /**
    * Gets a list of popular movies
    */
   private fun loadMovies(): Flow<PagingData<Movie>> {
       var movieListFromRepo: Flow<PagingData<Movie>> = emptyFlow()
       viewModelScope.launch {
           movieListFromRepo = getMovieListUseCase.getMostPopularMovies()
               .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
       }


       return movieListFromRepo
   }

   /**
    * Gets favorite movie list
    */
   private fun loadFavoriteMovies(): Flow<List<Movie>> {
       viewModelScope.launch {
           favoriteMovieList = getMovieListUseCase.getFavoriteMovies()
       }
       return favoriteMovieList
   }

   fun reloadMovies() {
       viewModelScope.launch {
           getMovieListUseCase.reloadMovies()
       }
   }

   private var movieListScrollState = 0
   fun saveMovieListScrollState(scrollIndex: Int) {
       movieListScrollState = scrollIndex
   }
   fun getMovieListScrollState():Int {
       return movieListScrollState
   }
}
```

I did a little searching about this error, and it might be possible that this error is caused because there’s no empty constructor in MovieListViewModel.kt. I tried to make one, but the solutions weren’t possible because the empty constructor will ask for GetMovieListUseCase inside this() or super(), which would do the same to MoviesRepository or its implementation MoviesRepositoryImpl, for which empty constructor is not possible because MovieRepository is an interface while MoviesRepositoryImpl has no static method.

This is GetMovieListUseCase .kt

```
package com.example.nameful.data.package000

import androidx.paging.PagingData
import com.example.nameful.data.repository.MoviesRepository
import com.example.nameful.data.repository.MoviesRepositoryImpl
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Movie
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import javax.inject.Inject

class GetMovieListUseCase @Inject constructor(
   private val popularMoviesRepository: MoviesRepository
) {



   suspend fun getMostPopularMovies(): Flow<PagingData<Movie>> {
       return popularMoviesRepository.getMostPopularMovies()
   }

   suspend fun getFavoriteMovies(): Flow<List<Movie>> {
       return popularMoviesRepository.getFavoriteMovies()
   }

   suspend fun reloadMovies() {
       popularMoviesRepository.reloadMovies()
   }

}
```

MoviesRepository.kt

```
package com.example.nameful.data.repository

import androidx.paging.PagingData
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Movie
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Provider
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Role
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import javax.inject.Inject


interface MoviesRepository {
   suspend fun getMostPopularMovies(): Flow<PagingData<Movie>>
   suspend fun getFavoriteMovies(): Flow<List<Movie>>
   suspend fun getMovieById(movieId: Int): Flow<Movie?>
   suspend fun toggleFavorite(movieId: Int)
   suspend fun reloadMovies()
   suspend fun getMovieCast(movieId: Int): Flow<List<Role?>>
   suspend fun getMovieProviders(movieId: Int): Flow<List<Provider?>>
}
```

MoviesRepositoryImpl.kt

```
package com.example.nameful.data.repository

import androidx.paging.ExperimentalPagingApi
import androidx.paging.PagingData
import androidx.paging.map
import com.example.nameful.data.Variables
import com.example.nameful.data.api.MovieRemoteMediator
import com.example.nameful.data.database.LocalDataSourceModule
import com.example.nameful.data.database.MovieDataSource
import com.example.nameful.data.database.NetworkDataSourceModule
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Movie
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Provider
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Role
import com.example.nameful.model.basic.Trailer
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import javax.inject.Inject

class MoviesRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
   @LocalDataSourceModule
   private val movieLocalDataSource: MovieDataSource,
   @NetworkDataSourceModule
   private val movieNetworkDataSource: MovieDataSource,
   dataRefreshManagerImpl: DataRefreshManager
) : MoviesRepository {



   @ExperimentalPagingApi
   val moviesRemoteMediator = MovieRemoteMediator(
       movieLocalDataSource,
       movieNetworkDataSource,
       dataRefreshManagerImpl
   )


   @ExperimentalPagingApi
   override suspend fun getMostPopularMovies(): Flow<PagingData<Movie>> {

       // return the paging source
       val mostPopularMovies =
           movieLocalDataSource.getPagedMovies(moviesRemoteMediator).map { pagingData ->
               pagingData.map {
                   it.poster = Variables.imageMidUrl+ it.poster
                   it.toDomain()
               }
           }
       return mostPopularMovies
   }

   @ExperimentalPagingApi
   override suspend fun reloadMovies() {
       moviesRemoteMediator.reload()
   }

   /**
    * Only local data source keeps favorite movies
    */
   override suspend fun getFavoriteMovies(): Flow<List<Movie>> {
       return movieLocalDataSource.getFavoriteMovies()
   }

   override suspend fun getMovieById(movieId: Int): Flow<Movie?> {
       val fullMovieDataFlow = movieLocalDataSource.getMovieById(movieId)
           .distinctUntilChanged()
           .map {
               if (it == null) {
                   insertFreshMovieDataToCache(movieId)
               } else {
                   if (it.trailer == null) {
                       insertTrailerToCache(it.movie_id)
                   }
               }
               it

           }
       return fullMovieDataFlow
   }

   override suspend fun toggleFavorite(movieId: Int) {
       movieLocalDataSource.toggleFavorite(movieId)
   }

   private suspend fun insertTrailerToCache(movieId: Int) {
       val trailer: Flow<Trailer?> = movieNetworkDataSource.getTrailer(movieId)
       if (trailer.count() > 0) {
           movieLocalDataSource.insertTrailer(movieId, trailer.first())
       }
   }

   private suspend fun insertFreshMovieDataToCache(movieId:Int) {
       val fullMovieData = movieNetworkDataSource.getMovieById(movieId)
       movieLocalDataSource.insertMovie(fullMovieData)
   }


   override suspend fun getMovieCast(movieId: Int): Flow<List<Role?>> {
       // get character list from the source of truth = database
       val movieCast = movieLocalDataSource.getMovieCast(movieId).map {
           when {
               it.isEmpty() -> {
                   insertCastToCache(movieId)
                   it
               }
               else -> {
                   it
               }
           }
       }
       return movieCast
   }

   private suspend fun insertCastToCache(movieId: Int) {
       // get cast list from network data source
       val castList: List<Role?> = movieNetworkDataSource.getFreshMovieCast(movieId)
       // insert into local data source
       movieLocalDataSource.insertCast(castList)
   }

   override suspend fun getMovieProviders(movieId: Int): Flow<List<Provider?>> {
       // get providers for this movie from the source of truth = database
       val movieProviders = movieLocalDataSource.getProviders(movieId).map {
           when {
               it.isEmpty() -> {
                   insertMovieProvidersToCache(movieId)
                   it
               }
               else -> {
                   it
               }
           }
       }
       return movieProviders
   }

   private suspend fun insertMovieProvidersToCache(movieId: Int) {
       // get providers from network data source
       val providerList: List<Provider?> = movieNetworkDataSource.getFreshProviders(movieId)
       // insert into local data source
       movieLocalDataSource.insertProviders(providerList)
   }

}
```

I also read that this has something to do with the class annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint, in my case it was MainActivity.kt.

```
package com.example.nameful

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.nameful.ui.MovieApp
import com.example.nameful.ui.main.MovieListViewModel
import com.example.nameful.ui.theme.PopularMoviesTheme
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

   @ExperimentalMaterialApi
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContent {
           PopularMoviesTheme {
               MovieApp()
           }
       }
   }

}
```

I tried to modify this class based on instructions on [init is not called when injecting viewModel using Hilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839757/init-is-not-called-when-injecting-viewmodel-using-hilt) but failed.

I've tried many suggestions, but things like changing the viewModel() into hiltViewModel() hadn't changed anything.

EDIT: here are the DI modules that I use in my project.

AppModule.kt

```
package com.example.nameful

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import com.example.nameful.data.repository.MoviesRepository
import com.example.nameful.data.repository.MoviesRepositoryImpl
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(application: Application): Context = application.applicationContext

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMoviesRepository(moviesRepositoryImpl: MoviesRepositoryImpl): MoviesRepository {
        return moviesRepositoryImpl
    }
}
```

ApiModule.kt

```
package com.example.nameful.data.api

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(builder: Retrofit.Builder): MoviesApiService {
        return builder
            .build()
            .create(MoviesApiService::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit.Builder {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .baseUrl("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        authenticationInterceptor: AuthenticationInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
        val loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor =
            HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(authenticationInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    }
}
```

DatabaseModule.kt

```
package com.example.nameful.data.database

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.nameful.data.dao.CastDao
import com.example.nameful.data.dao.MovieDao
import com.example.nameful.data.dao.ProviderDao
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): MovieDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, MovieDatabase::class.java, "movies").build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMovieDao(movieDatabase: MovieDatabase): MovieDao {
        return movieDatabase.movieDao()
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCastDao(movieDatabase: MovieDatabase): CastDao {
        return movieDatabase.castDao()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMovieProviderDao(movieDatabase: MovieDatabase): ProviderDao {
        return movieDatabase.providerDao()
    }
}
```

DataRefreshManagerBinding.kt

```
package com.example.nameful.data.datarefreshmanager

import com.example.nameful.data.repository.DataRefreshManager
import dagger.Binds
import dagger.Module
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal abstract class DataRefreshManagerBinding {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindDataRefreshManager(dataRefreshManagerIml: DataRefreshManagerImpl): DataRefreshManager
}
```

MoviesRepositoryBinding.kt

```
package com.example.nameful.data.repository

import dagger.Binds
import dagger.Module
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal abstract class DependenciesBindings {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindRepository(moviesRepositoryImpl: MoviesRepositoryImpl): MoviesRepository
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide your DI modules here. It might be because any of the dependency is missing.
As for your viewModel instance, just remove the UseCase once and comment the other. Then you can log the ViewModel init block to see if it initializes or not.

Comment: @NareshNK in MovieAppNavigation.kt? And by “remove the UseCase once” do you mean removing `private val getMovieListUseCase: GetMovieListUseCase` inside MovieListViewModel's constructor?

Comment: Yes, removing the variable just to check an empty ViewModel init.

Comment: I can confirm I had a working viewmodel when I was using manual dependency injection. Now dependencies are satisfied with Hilt, but the runtime error keeps popping up.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code , it is visible that `GetMovieListUseCase` need instance of `MoviesRepository` to create instance of `GetMovieListUseCase` and here `MoviesRepository` is interface and implementation is provided by `MoviesRepositoryImpl` class . This we know but how hilt will get to know about it .. So for that you need to create module as mentioned below

Create new file . Let's say `AppModule.kt` and paste below code

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMoviesRepository(moviesRepositoryImpl: MoviesRepositoryImpl): MoviesRepository {
        return moviesRepositoryImpl
    }
}
```

Here we are mentioning that whenever hilt need to create object of `MoviesRepository` , it can use object of `MoviesRepositoryImpl`

Comment: I just added the function provideMoviesRepository that you've given, and I still got the same error. By the way, I already have AppModule before, in which there's a function fun provideContext(application: Application): Context = application.applicationContext. It also had annotations Singleton and Provides

Comment: If dependency is not satisfied, error message clearly states that. The error posted by OP is not a dependency error.